Inconsistant case in naming git branches causes message on fetch
Using git for windows and git bash, everytime I fetch my repository, I have
 - [deleted]                 (none)                  -> origin/Bug/aabbcc
 * [new branch]              bug/aabbcc              -> origin/bug/aabbcc

due to the upper case "B" of bug, I guess.
If I fetch multiple times in a row, this will appear every-time (so as I understand it, no change is done despite the message).
If I do git remote prune origin, then a first fetch will recreate branch with a lowercase "b", and another fetch will show once again the same problem.
How could I avoid this without modifying the distant repo? (this branch is not mine, and I can't change it)
Additional information:

There is not one but plenty branches (all under Bug) that cause this problem.
I do not use any of these branches. They are branches from colleagues that I never checked out.


Does the branch file in .git/refs/heads have an uppercase or lowercase b? If the latter, can you rename .git/refs/heads/bug to .git/refs/heads/Bug? What about the branch entry in .git/config, does that have correct casing (and if not, what happens if you fix it)?

Does this answer help you?

@larsks in .git/refs/heads there is ... neither. It does not exist because I never checked out the branch. In .git/refs/remotes/origin however there is a Bug folder that I renamed bug and now I have the opposite problem on some other branches: [deleted] ... -> origin/bug/ddd and [new branch] .... -> /Bug/ddd

@sayanel I would suggest you to ask your colleagues to agree on one way of writing the branch names so you don’t have both bug/something and Bug/something.

The instructions are to always be lowercase, but they use GUI tools and not command line so they are not really bothered by these kind of mistakes. A good solution could be hooks to enforce the rules, but that's beyond my power

Windows is case-insensitive. I don't know about the internals of git, but judging by your report, it seems that it is at least partially case-sensitive.
I would make order by
1. Creating a backup branch
git checkout bug/aabbcc
git branch temp

2. Attempting to rename the branch
git branch -m origin/Bug/aabbcc

3. Check whether everything is all right
4. If not everything is all right
Then change the upstream as
git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to your_new_remote/branch_name

5. If this didn't work
remove your local branches with similar name, checkout your temp branch just created and create a branch with the correct name, like git branch Bug/aabbcc
6. If all fails
Clone the repo again, checkout to the missing branch and other branches you need. And then the problem will surely disappear.

I forgot to mention in the question: the branch is not checked out, I have never and will never use it. It is just some branch that is on the repo. So these do not apply. I did clone again the repo, and it did not help
